# How to use jQuery to select an image that is returned in a div with multiple images?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below images are all returned and displayed on page via this JavaScript/jQuery:

```
for(var j = 0; j < imageURLs.length; j++){
    $('#imgs').append("<img src='" + imageURLs[j] + "'/>");  
    $('#username').append(Username[j]); 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="imgs"></div>
```

I want the user to be able to click on any of the images and pass the image/username into a variable.

I thought I could use $this to select the individual images/usernames, but that just seems to return "imgs" each time. How can I use jQuery to select and capture the actual username/images? Do I need to use `.mouseover()` before adding the item?

```
$('imgs').click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         var selectedFriend = $(this).attr("id");
         console.log(selectedFriend);
     });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Did you mean `$("#imgs img")` or `$("#imgs").find("img")` as a selector? As it stands, you're binding to a `<imgs>` element

Comment: In addition to above comment you should use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically generated elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your selector is incorrect.** When you are using `$('imgs')` jQuery is searching for `imgs` element which doesn't exists. Thus you need to change your selector to [ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Apart from above you are creating `img` element dynamically, thus you need to use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$('#imgs').on('click', 'img', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var selectedFriend = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(selectedFriend);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try having the append to define the onclick event too.

```
$('#imgs').append("<img src='" + imageURLs[j] + "' onclick='doStuff(this)'/>");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following (not tested):

```
 for(var j = 0; j < imageURLs.length; j++){
      $('#imgs').append("<img src='" + imageURLs[j] + "' id='PUT_YOUR_UNIQUE_ID_HERE' />");  
      $('#username').append(Username[j]); 
 }

 $('imgs').on('click', 'img', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var selectedFriend = $(this).attr("id");
      console.log(selectedFriend);
 });
```